# Java Array list of object

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I hava a pojo class with getters and setters:ApplicationsPojo.class

Then I have

```
public static ArrayList<List<ApplicationPojo>> list = new ArrayList<List<ApplicationPojo>>();
```

I put items in the list with:

```
DownloadLists.list.add(Arrays.asList(new ApplicationPojo(id, name, developer, size, logoImg)))
```

now I would like to check if the objects in the list has a reference to an string (Cat);

How to do that?

Comment: do you mean if the name of an ojbect in the list is "CAT" ?

Comment: no i want to know if an object has a reference to a string for example (cat)

Comment: What are the data types of you Pojo member variables? I assume you want to check if any of the members (which one?) is a reference to a specific String (do you actually want to compare for reference, ie, same object, or for value?). One more question: Why do you use a list of lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate manually. If you know that the specific string you are searching for can only be found in "id" or in "name" or in "developer" or in "size" or in "logoImg", you should only include those specific items into your iteration.

If you have large amounts of data and you need your search to perform well you'd need a (much) more complicated solution (probably too complicated for a beginner), please ask again in that case.

If you don't need a well-performing search algorithm just iterate through your ArrayList, comparing the contents of all the "ApplicationPojo"-items (id, name etc.) which may apply to that specific search with the string you search for by string compare